# Separating classes in java. Eg. virtual keyboard (with activelisteners) and another class to receive input from the keyboard class

Tags: java, class, keyboard

I have a virtual keyboard class which implements a QWERTY alphanumeric only on-screen keyboard using JButtons in JAVA.
I have installed actionlisteners to each button so that whenever the button is clicked on the label of the button is logged.

What I want to do is that while keeping the class for keyboard separate, I want to create an instance of the keyboard class so that it receives an input and it passes it back to the main class and then that can happen in a loop. Just like how you can use has.nextLine() to keep on asking for input, I want to be able to do this by creating an instance of the on screen keyboard class.

I have already written the keyboard class and it works nicely and but the problem is that the integers are local to the keyboard class and I cant figure out a way to get it outside of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use observer pattern . I am not using swing here but just to show to show it works.

**Make Keyboard class Observable**

```
    import java.util.Observable;

    public class Keybaord extends Observable {

        private String keyThatIsPressed;

        public void setKeyThatIsPressed(String keyThatIsPressed) {
            this.keyThatIsPressed = keyThatIsPressed;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(keyThatIsPressed);
        }

        public String getKeyThatIsPressed(){
            return keyThatIsPressed;
        }

 }
```

**Make your main class Observer**

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class MainClass implements Observer {
    private String keyThatIsPressed;

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable,
            Object object) {
        if (object instanceof String) {
            this.keyThatIsPressed = (String) object;
            System.out.println("Key that was unlucky enough to get pressed was: "
                    + keyThatIsPressed);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer to the question. I was just wondering, what is the usual practice to deal with the kind of the thing that I trying to do. I mean how do you usually approach this kind of problem. Do you usually separate classes or you keep them in the same file so you dont have to use observers, etc?

Comment: Definitely separate. Using observer while not necessary,is a good practice. Yes downside is if you have too many observers it can become difficult to track them but then it is this kind of loose coupling that this pattern does cater for. I use seam with has an annotation of this pattern keeping the setter cleaner.But then of course using seam just for this is overkill . You can ofcourse if you choose, develop your own annotation and not plug the code in setter.